# Image is not rendered when I moved routers from server file(Entry point file) to controller file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am so confused that I have just moved two routers from my server file to controller file to follow the MVC format. Now I can not see logo image on that routers. I can see other pictures that are in view files(addMovies.handlebars) Logo(png file) is located in my main.handlebars file and I am using addMovie.handlebars as a view to render with content of main.handlebars.

This my main.handlebars file that has logo image that is not being rendered:

```
<head>  
// some code
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="logo"><img src="./images/logo/logof.png" alt="STREAMDOG"></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="/allMovieTV">Movies</a></li>
            </li>
            <li class="item button"><a href="/login">Log In</a></li>
            <li class="item button secondary"><a href="/signup">Sign Up</a></li>
            <li class="toggle"><span class="bars"></span></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </header>

    <main>
    {{{body}}}
    </main>

    <footer class="footer">
       // some code
    </footer>
</body>
```

this is my controller file(movies.js)

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const movieModel = require("../models/movieDB");

router.get("/add", (req, res) => {
    res.render("addMovie", {

    })
});

router.post("/add", (req, res) => {
    const newMovie = {
        movieName: req.body.name,
        about: req.body.about,
        imdb: req.body.imdb,
        length: req.body.length,
        tags: req.body.tags,
        releaseDate: req.body.releaseDate,
        directors: req.body.directors,
        // featured: req.body.featured,
        type: req.body.type,
        Rprice: req.body.Rprice,
        Bprice: req.body.Bprice,

    }

    const movie = new movieModel(newMovie);
    movie.save()
    .then(() => {
        res.redirect("/allMovieTV");
    })
    .catch(err=>console.log(`error occured while saving the movie ${err}`));
})
module.exports = router;
```

This is how I am referring to those routes in server.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');

const app = express();
var hbs = exphbs.create({ /* config */ });

// Defining static folder
app.use(express.static('public'));

//Importing controllers
const moviesController = require("./controllers/movies.js");

app.use("/new/",moviesController);
```

I do not understand how the front-end is being changed when I am moving code of back-end!

Please explain if I need to add more information here.

Comment: Please show what the `src` of the image logo image is and where you handle that request (e.g. `express.static()`). You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67082849/edit) your question to add details.

Comment: I don't know but I think it should be express.router instead of express.Router. R should be in lowercase.

Comment: @ShivamSharma I checked documentation here: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html   
At the end this is explained for middleware and routing system I think problem is something else.

Comment: A debugging suggests: open the web-browser's console when viewing your page, see what's going on with the static files. Maybe the url goes incorrect? Or you open the logo image's url yourself and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to start any source path with "./images" we should write "/images".

Line, that needs to be changed.

```
        <li class="logo"><img src="/images/logo/logof.png" alt="STREAMDOG"></li>
```